What was this SOS signaling car?
Today on the highway, there was a seemingly rather new car - I did not take note of the make, looked like a medium-sized sedan. It signaled SOS (... - - - ...) with the warning lights, the headlight flasher and the horn, clearly synchronized, for about the 2 minutes it took me to pass it in regularly flowing traffic. It then took a off-ramp, still signaling.
As it was 3 things at the same time, perfectly synchronized, it was clearly not the driver using those three controls perfectly. I was busy with my head on a swivel checking for dangers, assuming the driver wanted to warn others of some problem, so I did not pay super great attention to the inside of the car itself, but it seemed to me that there was just the driver, and he looked fine. I.e., he had his hands on the steering wheel and was not slumped over or something like that.
I know that some cars, including mine, have a dedicated SOS button, but I thought that just called the emergency services. Is the behavior of this car a well-known or even standard feature? Even if the driver pressed the SOS button by accident (or to try what it does... which is not a good idea because it floods the services with bogus calls, of course), I would have assumed he would just press it again to disable the blaring horn?
This happened in Germany.

It might help to know in what country you saw this.

It happened in Germany, @DavidRecallsMonica.
